# Getting undefined value from a global variable whilst assigning new value

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

This is my Javascript game, which is basically brick braker without the bricks. I'm currently getting a undefined error on line 188 (ball).
It's been declared as a global variable and is then being assigned new values.
My JS skills are elow average and have been scratching my head over this for a while.
If any one can give me pointers on actually getting this thing running i would be very appreciative!!
Thanks in advance.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>Pong Racker</title>



   </head>
   <body>

    <canvas id="backgroundCanvas" width="900" height="500" style="border:2px solid #404080;">


      Your browser doesn't support HTML5. Please install a newer browser version :
      <br />
      <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie9_bow_Bing&WT.srch=1&mtag=SearBing">
        http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie9_bow_Bing&WT.srch=1&mtag=SearBing</a>



    </canvas>

    <svg  id="svgRoot" width="900" height="500">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r=10 id="ball" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white" />
      <rect id="pad" height="15px" width="150px" x="400" y="350" rx="10" ry="20"/>
  </svg> 

  <style>canvas, svg {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
  }
</style>



<script type="text/javascript">

    startGame();


    // Getting elements
    var pad = document.getElementById("pad");
    var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
    var svg = document.getElementById("svgRoot");
    var message = document.getElementById("message"); 



    // Ball
    //var ballRadius = ball.r.baseVal.value;
    var ballRadius = ball.r.baseVal.value;
    var ballX;
    var ballY;
    var previousBallPositionx = 0;
    var previousBallPositiony = 260;
    var ballDirectionX;
    var ballDirectionY;
    var ballSpeed = 10; 



    // Pad
    var padWidth = pad.width.baseVal.value;
    var padHeight = pad.height.baseVal.value;
    var padX;
    var padY;
    var padSpeed = 0;
    var inertia = 0.80; 



    // Misc.
    var minX = ballRadius;
    var minY = ballRadius;
    var maxX;
    var maxY;
    var startDate; 



    // Collisions
    function collideWithWindow() {
       alert("collideWithWindow");
       if (ballX < minX) {
        ballX = minX;
        ballDirectionX *= -1.0;
    }
    else if (ballX > maxX) {
        ballX = maxX;
        ballDirectionX *= -1.0;
    }

    if (ballY < minY) {
        ballY = minY;
        ballDirectionY *= -1.0;
    }
    else if (ballY > maxY) {
        ballY = maxY;
        ballDirectionY *= -1.0;
        lost();
    }
}

function collideWithPad() {
    if (ballX + ballRadius < padX || ballX - ballRadius > padX + padWidth)
        return;

    if (ballY + ballRadius < padY)
        return;

    ballX = previousBallPositionx;
    ballY = previousBallPositiony;
    ballDirectionY *= -1.0;

    var dist = ballX - (padX + padWidth / 2);

    ballDirectionX = 2.0 * dist / padWidth;

    var square = Math.sqrt(ballDirectionX * ballDirectionX + ballDirectionY * ballDirectionY);
    ballDirectionX /= square;
    ballDirectionY /= square;
}




    // Pad movement
    function movePad() {
        padX += padSpeed;

        padSpeed *= inertia;

        if (padX < minX)
            padX = minX;

        if (padX + padWidth > maxX)
            padX = maxX - padWidth;
    }


    registerMouseMove(document.getElementById("gameZone"), function (posx, posy, previousX, previousY) {
     padSpeed += (posx - previousX) * 0.2;
 });

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
       alert("keyboard");
       switch (evt.keyCode) {
            // Left arrow
            case 37:
            padSpeed -= 10;
            break;
            // Right arrow   
            case 39:
            padSpeed += 10;
            break;
        }
    }, true);




    function checkWindow() {
        maxX = window.innerWidth - minX;
        maxY = window.innerHeight - 130 - 40 - minY;
        padY = maxY - 30;
    } 




    function gameLoop() {
       alert("game loop");

       movePad();

        // Movements
        previousBallPositionx = ballX;
        previousBallPositiony = ballY;
        ballX += ballDirectionX * ballSpeed;
        ballY += ballDirectionY * ballSpeed;

        // Collisions
        collideWithWindow();
        collideWithPad();

        // Ball
        ball.setAttribute("cx", ballX);
        ball.setAttribute("cy", ballY);

        // Pad
        pad.setAttribute("x", padX);
        pad.setAttribute("y", padY);

    }


    function initGame() {
       alert("init game");
        //message.style.visibility = "hidden";
        checkWindow();

        padX = (window.innerWidth - padWidth) / 2.0;

        ballX = window.innerWidth / 2.0;
        ballY = maxY - 60;

        previousBallPositionx = ballX;
        previousBallPositiony = ballY;

        padSpeed = 0;

        ballDirectionX = Math.random();
        ballDirectionY = -1.0;

        gameLoop();
    }


    window.onresize = initGame; 



    var gameIntervalID = -1;

    function startGame() {
       alert("start");
       initGame();

       if (gameIntervalID > -1)
        clearInterval(gameIntervalID);
    startDate = (new Date()).getTime(); ;
    gameIntervalID = setInterval(gameLoop, 16);
}
document.getElementById("newGame").onclick = startGame; 

//Game lost
var gameIntervalID = -1;
function lost() {
    clearInterval(gameIntervalID);
    gameIntervalID = -1;

    message.innerHTML = "Game over !";
    message.style.visibility = "visible";
}



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are calling your `startGame` function before you have even assigned a value to `ball`.

Comment: Yes, but start game is a bit of a wrong term, start game is a function that basically starts setting up bits and then calls initgame. the game actually begins within the loop i believe is what i tried to do.

Comment: sorry just understood your message just moved the startgame below the variables and now im hitting the game loop repeatidly :D

Comment: Currently gettign an error on 143 which is mouselistener  not defined and 244 which is a message = null

Comment: Javascript is sequential. This means you need to define functions/vars before you call them otherwise they are `undefined` when they are called.

Comment: would that be like stating that a messgage to be a string in a global variable>

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>

callMethod();

var test = 10;

function callOtherMethod() {
    console.log(test);
}

function callMethod() {
    callOtherMethod();
}

</script>
</body>
```

When I run this, it logs "undefined". I think thats your problem, as well.

When I move the `callMethod()` below the `var test = 10`, it works.

Comment: I managed to get the game working, i removed the mouse interaction and just left key left and right arrow interaction and now it runs. Also replaced the message with na alert for now. Can work on that later. but thanks for the help :D